# IS it possible to leave :active pseudo class active after clicking it?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

You click on some text, and that text triggers a div to show up, a form with other words, hopefully. Of course when you let loose of the right mouse button it disappears, I want to make it remain.

How, if you know?

Comment: Sounds like there's probably a better way to actually do what you are trying. Care to elaborate or post code on what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: I've been struggling for a couple of hours now trying to make an already created user sign up form to show up right beside the button which people have to click to sign up and I want to not use Javascript, nor JQuery, I use Ruby on Rails. Is there no other possible way to make a div show up besides the sign up button besides using Javascript and etceteral similarities.

Comment: Those are strange constraints. This would easily be accomplished through jQuery, which has no conflicts with Rails. Any specific reason why you do not want to use Javascript?

Comment: Seems like some basic JS even without JQuery could do what you are looking to do with very few lines of code; any reason you are trying to avoid it?

Comment: But to answer your initial question, without using any sort of JS I don't believe it is possible to alter the pseudo class.

Comment: If I told you my personal reasons, you would only view me as pathetic and totally lack of reasoning. So you don't know of any other way besides this Jquery and Javascript method?

Comment: Oh well, I guess I'll just have to adjust my design to pure CSS then, I don't think it will be such a big problem after all. Thanks for all help though!